# Alex TTS voice is automatically deleted

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, text-to-speech

I'm using the TTS voices for some of my app. Sometimes I download new voices to check how they sound to probably move to them later. I heard that Alex voice is one of the best free voices on iOS, so I downloaded it. It weighs around 800 MB, which is pretty much.

After some time I've filled up my device storage, so only around 50 MB are left. After that I proceeded to filling it up downloading new apps and at some moment this Alex voice started to show app as not installed, so in the list of voices it shows up with cloud button to the right. Also, in the app where I used it, some other voice started to speak instead of Alex one.

Is it possible that iOS automatically deletes some too heavyweight voices in order to make more free space?

Comment: I know of the auto-offload feature for apps and I would think something very similar happens here: iOS detects it needs more space and offloads - instead of apps - your voice first.

Comment: @X_841, yeah, agree, the logic seems close to this, but for apps this option can be enabled or disabled and it explicitly says that it can happen, but for voices I couldn't find any mentions neither in documentation, nor in the iOS settings

Comment: True, they should at least state somewhere that this might happen. Maybe you can describe this to Apple Support? I'd be interesting in the outcome

Comment: @X_841, yeah, good idea, let me do that and comment here if they will answer!